# How to reveal letters if correct to what is inputted

Tags: python

I am creating a hangman game , where a user will enter a word in which another user will have to guess.
I have got the word to print with dashes, however when I input a letter which is in the word, I cannot get it to remove the dashes.

```
#output a game of hangman

letters= ["A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z"]
for i in range(1):
print("Welcome to Hangman")
word_guess = str(input("Please enter a word for user 2 to guess:"))
print("Word to be guessed:"+str(word_guess))
length_of_word=len(word_guess)
display=("-"*length_of_word)
print("Display:"+str(display))

for i in range(1):
 print("Welcome to Hangman Player 2")
letter_guess=str(input("Please guess a letter:"))
if letter_guess in word_guess:
print("Yay you have a match")
display=display.rstrip(display)
print(display)
```

Comment: Your code formatting is wrong. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: So your next steps are determining at what index the letter occurs in the word and then using those indexes to update the values in your "-------" string to that letter then print it again.

Also, read the string module documentation and never have to type out the alphabet like that again.

Comment: Python is strict on indentation and your code shows no indentation, which probably means it is not an accurate reflection of your code. Please ensure that your code displayed reflects your actual code.

Also, please provide the output being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

## Hangman

Try this code, is not refinished, but it works. Maybe it can give you some ideas. To work, you got to be connected, otherwise put the file with words on the computer.

[image]

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from random import choice


w0 = urlopen("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Xethron/Hangman/master/words.txt")
w = [str(x).replace("b'", "").replace("\\n", "") for x in w0]
word = choice(w)
word = word.replace("'", "")
strips = list("_" * len(word)) 
chosen = []


def guess():
    y = input("Guess a letter: ")
    if y in chosen:
        print("You have choose this letter yet, retry...")
        guess()
    chosen.append(y)
    if y in word:
        if "_" not in strips:
            print("GREAT, YOU WIN!")
            print()
            print()
            pass
        print("Great the letter is in the word")
        indexes = [x for x, y2 in enumerate(word) if y == y2]
        for ind in indexes:
            strips[ind] = y
        for ch in strips:
            print("[" + ch + "]", end='')
        print("You`ve choosen: ", "".join(chosen))
        print()
        print()
        guess()
    else:
        print("This letter is not in the word, try again")
        print("".join(strips))
        print("You`ve choosen: ", "".join(chosen))


def start():
    for ch in range(len(word)):
        guess()
    print("Game over " * 5)
    print("The word was " + word)
    print("\n" * 5)


print("HANGMAN - Giovanni Gianni Gatto")
print("print start() to restart")
print()
start()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a hangman lying around which I adapted to your needs. What you need is to have a list with found items `[]` and when you print the word to display you show only letters which are in the found items else `_`.

`print(' '.join(i if i in found else '_' for i in secretword))`

Here is a full example of a game where it asks for `one_guess` (a function) until the length of found items is equal too the length of the set of the secretword (set removes duplicate letters). Try it:

```
def print_word():
    print(' '.join(i if i in found else '_' for i in secretword))

def valid_input():
    while True:
        guess = input("Guess a letter: ({})".format(''.join(i for i in alpha)))
        if guess in alpha:
            alpha.remove(guess)
            return guess
        else:
            print("Not valid input!")

def one_guess():
    print_word()
    guess = valid_input()

    if guess in letters:
        print("You found one!\n")
        letters.remove(guess)
        found.append(guess)
    else:
        print("You didn't find one!\n")

secretword = "animal"
alpha = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
letters = list(set(secretword))
found = []

while True:
    one_guess()
    if len(set(secretword)) == len(found):
        print("You won!")
```